# Expression " make no mistake about it"

Tags: expressions

What is the meaning of the expression " to make no mistake about something".

Thank you people.

Comment: It's not (usually) "to make no mistake ...", but rather the imperative "Make no mistake about it."  It means that "You should understand clearly" that what was just stated or what is about to be stated is true (according to the speaker).  It's an emphatic statement.

Comment: So, in this example: " Make no mistake about it, I will be there" and "Without a shadow of a doubt, I will be there", both of them are right?

Comment: Yep, both mean roughly the same thing.

Comment: How about "Don't doubt it, ....".

Comment: It is also a good one to be used in this situation. Thank you.

Comment: It has a [dictionary entry](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/make-no-mistake-about-it?q=make+no+mistake) all of its own.

Answer (score 1):

As Hot Licks points out in comments above, "make no mistake about [something]" usually appears in the form of an imperative declaration that amounts to a warning not to misunderstand the most important conclusion to be drawn from a longer discussion or commentary—which often follows immediately after the phrase.

I associate the phrase with Richard Nixon, who used it often as a prefatory phrase in speeches and extemporaneous remarks (another Nixon favorite was "Let me say this about that:"). For example, from [Speech of Vice President Nixon, Woodrow Wilson Park, Birmingham, AL](http://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/ws/?pid=25464) (August 26, 1960):

> Now you have heard some comments about the weakness of America militarily, and I just want to set the record straight here today. **Make no mistake about it**. America today is the strongest nation in the world militarily. We have the kind of strength that I have referred to, and we can and will maintain that level of strength in the years ahead.

And from [Remarks of the Vice President, Rear Train Platform, Dayton, OH](http://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/ws/?pid=25467) (October 26, 1960):

> Second, I pledge to you that we will keep this economy growing, as I have indicated, moving forward on all fronts, as it has not moved forward ever in our history. But **make no mistake about it**, when we talk about America standing still, let's just look around America and we will see that we've made more progress in this administration than we ever made in the Truman administration. We don't want to go back to those policies.

And from [Remarks of the Vice President at Downtown Rally, Fresno, CA](http://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/ws/?pid=25304) (November 4, 1960):

> There are things wrong with our education, but—**make no mistake about it**—I've seen Soviet education and I've seen our own, and we have the finest schools and our youngsters get the best education in the world, and **make no mistake about it**, and we can be proud of that, too. [Cheers and applause.]

However, the phrase "make no mistake about [something]" goes back to at least the first half of the nineteenth century. The earliest Google Books match for the phrase in its imperative form is from John Poole, [*Phineas Quiddy*](https://books.google.com/books?id=-C8aAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA238&dq=%22Phineas+Quiddy%22+%22Make+No+Mistake+about+it%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi1lOat8oHKAhVY4mMKHYI6BBIQ6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=%22Make%20No%20Mistake%20about%20it%22&f=false), in *The New Monthly Magazine* (June 1842):

> "He found great fault with his Claret last time, sir."
>
> "Yes—I know. He is to try Mull and Mixem's wine, the eighteen shilling claret, green corks; the same that Sir Archibald McSwizzle and Lord Ernest Fitzfuddleton always drink. **Make no mistake about it**."

And from "[Minutes of Evidence Taken Before Select Committee on the Bridgewater Election Petition](https://books.google.com/books?id=9ClcAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA15&dq=%22make+no+mistake+about%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjq_Z7Q7oHKAhUU4mMKHS2KCN8Q6AEIIzAB#v=onepage&q=%22make%20no%20mistake%20about%22&f=false)" (April 17, 1866), in Great Britain, Parliament, House of Commons, *Public Bills* (1866):

> 767. How long before you went to the poll, as you have described, was it that you saw Mr. Smith the pawnbroker at the "Golden Lion"?—It might be three-quarters of an hour.
> 768. Before you polled?—Yes.
> 769. Now **make no mistake about that**. You pledge yourself that you saw Mr. Smith the pawnbroker at the "Golden Lion" that morning at the time you mention?—Yes.

Nonimperative use of the phrase goes back considerably farther—to at least James Usher, [*A Free Examination of the Common Methods Employed to Prevent the Growth of Popery*](https://books.google.com/books?id=DJthAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA64&dq=%22make+no+mistake+about%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwib9qCK9IHKAhUX52MKHUwYAnc4ChDoAQgsMAM#v=onepage&q=%22make%20no%20mistake%20about%22&f=false) (1781):

> Now, in order that these Gentlemen may **make no mistake about it**, I will shew them in what circumstance the being a Papist abates of his evidence.